# install haskell-platform on nixOS

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, nix, nixos

It's said to be a good starting point for haskell-beginners: the haskell platform. unfortunately, it looks like it's been removed from the nix-os package manager.

What would be the preferred way to quickly get this up and running on a nix-os system?

Comment: [User’s Guide to the Haskell Infrastructure](http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure) sounds relevant.

Comment: Have you tried `nix-env -iA nixos.ghc`? What are you missing?

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy of the nix packagers is not to assemble the platform packages and tools together, but that it is more "nixy" to just provide a the various ghc compiler versions and tools individually in a standard nix way. Since nix also handles haskell package management for you, the platform approach indeed just provides friction in this case, and you're better off following the User's Guide to Haskell Infrastructure from nix as linked above.